# Does inheritance without adding new fields/methods make sense?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'm currently wondering if inheritance is good when we don't want to introduce add fields/methods in a derived class. Let's suppose I have a base class named `Place`, and derived classes - `Toilet` and `Restaurant`. Both `Toilet` and `Restaurant` do not introduce new fields nor methods. They just allow me to check whether a `Place` is a `Toilet` or a `Restaurant` - useful when creating a `List<Place>`:

```
if(Place is Toilet)
    ...
else if(Place is Restaurant)
    ...
```

Is this a bad practice? Or should I create an enum called PlaceType and put it in the Place class, and then check it when necessary? I prefer using the first solution, since the new fields & methods can be easily added if needed in the future.

Comment: There is no right or wrong answer here which is why I'm voting to close this as primarily based on opinion. On one hand you can say that introducing descendants here does in fact *add* something, it adds *type identity*. As you've shown, you can check if a place is a restaurant or a toilet, even if the actual object doesn't add or change any built-in behavior or properties. But, on the other hand, since they don't add or change any behavior or properties, *except* for type identity, why not simply store the *type of place* as a property of a `Place`? Again, no right or wrong answers. Opinions.

Comment: It's often done with [Exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/how-to-create-user-defined-exceptions). Whether it is a good idea in a specific case is a subjective question.

Comment: Primarily opinion based. That said, should you do this routinely? Probably not. Is there a place for it where a type-based is otherwise in use? Maybe. But note that in your example, you should be asking yourself, why do you care if a place is a toilet or a restaurant? What would you do with that information? And why can't that difference be encapsulated somehow _in the object itself_, rather than some external code that is apparently inspecting the type?

Comment: I would say: *no, it doesn't make sense in such simple case". An additional field with place type in the place class would also let you determine the type. Think, would you have hundreds of classes inheriting the `Person` class just to indicate what surname someone has? Like `SmithPerson`, `AndersonPerson` etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't consider what you're doing a bad practice per se, for the reason you stated yourself:

> new fields & methods can be easily added if needed in the future

However I would personally go with the second option you proposed:

> create an enum called PlaceType and put it in the Place class

Mainly for the reason that if you ever decide that you want to store your *places* in a database or serialize them into JSON, having a field that indicates the type will make it a lot easier.

If you ever need to introduce *type* dependent features, using a mixture of both, would probably be the best option:

```
enum PlaceType
{
    Toilet,
    Restaurant
}

class Place
{
    public Place(PlaceType type)
    {
        Type = type;
    }

    public PlaceType Type { get; }
}

class Toilet : Place
{
    public Toilet() : base(PlaceType.Toilet)
    {

    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

In addition to this, I'd like to add that you should probably avoid using the `is` keyword to perform actions depending on the type of *place* (as shown in your code snippet).
Most of the times this can be done more nicely using [Polymorphism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/polymorphism).

For example, if all those places should be visit able, you could do something like this:

```
class Place
{
    public virtual void Visit()
    {
        // What happens during visit,
        // if the derived class doesn't override the Visit method
    }
}

class Toilet : Place
{
    public override void Visit()
    {
        // Visit functionality specific to the Toilet Place
    }
}
```

Now if you have a `List<Place>` and call `Visit` on one of its members it will call either the default implementation of `Visit` in the base class or if the method is overwritten in the derived class it will call this method. This allows you to get rid of a lot of `if` and `switch` statements down the line, once you introduce more *places* that should also be visit able.

Comment: If there's an enum with place type in the place class, what's the point of the inherited type? I wouldn't recommend this "mixture" at all, looks too redundant.

Comment: @WiktorZychla OP said that he might be adding place dependent methods and properties in the future, which is why I kept his inheritance. As long as there are no type dependent functionalities, this would be redundant, I totally agree! I edited my answer to reflect, that this mixture would only make sense, if there were type dependent functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do this; however, when you have to do `if(Place is Toilet) ... else if(Place is Restaurant) ...`, then you can probably improve your design and use polymorphysm instead.

Let's make an example (and let's use switch with pattern matching). `Console.WriteLine` is just a placeholder for your real code.

```
switch (place)
{
    case Toilet toilet:
        Console.WriteLine($"This is toilet {toilet.Name}");
        break;
    case Restaurant restaurant:
        Console.WriteLine($"This is restaurant {restaurant.Name}");
        break;
}
```

Instead, add an abstract (or virtual) method `Writeline()` to `Place` and override it in concrete places

```
public abstract class Place
{
    public Place(string name) => Name = name;
    public string Name { get; }
    public abstract void WriteLine();
}

public class Toilet : Place
{
    public Toilet (string name) : base(name) {}
    public override void WriteLine() => Console.WriteLine($"This is toilet {Name}");
}

// do the corresponding thing with Restaurant
```

Now you can print with

```
place.WriteLine(); // `place` could be a Toilet or a Restaurant or
                   // anything else deriving from Place. No "if" or "switch" required.
```

and if you add more place types in future, there is no need to add any new `else if` or `case` spread all over your code. Just let the new classes implement the required methods.

See also: [Polymorphism (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/polymorphism)